# Is there a way to tell if the value entered in <v-combobox> is new value or selected in the item list?

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify.js

Can I know whether the input value of  is selected from the item list or newly entered?

For example, if you have a  like this:
[image]

I want to know whether I selected "Programming" from the item list or entered "Programming" manually.

Please tell me how.

Thanks.